# Storyboarding iOS 5 model dialog via segue

Tags: ios

I have the following code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self    
action:@selector(showAddNewView)];

- (void) showAddNewView
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addNew" sender:self];
}
```

The segue executes fine, but the view is suppose to have a navigation bar at the top w/ title "Add New Recipe". But it doesn't display that part. If I change the transition to push, it looks fine.

Here is my scene:

[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT: I am having trouble with the answer, I had it working but now it is crashing again...

[image: Scenes]

[image]

Comment: you are not really saying what the sueque is doing now? modal I guess from your explanation?

Comment: What exactly is the crash you are getting?  Can you provide some log output?

Comment: I have updated, it doesn't give me a crash error, but I get the screenshot shown above

Comment: GOT IT, it was an outlet on the loose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modal segues bring an entirely new view controller on top of whatever is currently being used.  If you wish the new view controller to have the navigation bar with that default behavior, then you need to make the root view controller that is appearing from the modal transition a navigation controller.

Comment: Do I create a view that subclasses UINavigationController or do I subclass UIViewController and add a UINavigationController, or something else?

Comment: Instead of having a modal segue to your lone recipe view controller, make the segue to a UINavigationController whose root view controller is the recipe view controller

Comment: I tried that. I removed the segue, added a new UINavigationController, created a new segue named that segue addNew, then tried [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addNew" sender:self]; It crashes with no errors in the console

Comment: I thought I got it, but then I deleted it and tried to replicate it. And it is crashing again. I have updated my original question.